# Is there a way i can specify the github action workflow to use powershell 7 instead of default powershell 5?

Tags: powershell, yaml, github-actions

I have a workflow that is going to run a powershell script on a local runner, i have tried arguing with chatgpt but it cannot give me a correct answer to how i can spesify that i want to use powershell 7. This is needed because one of the modules used in the powershell script is not supported in earlier versions of powershell.

This is what the workflow yaml file is currently looking like:

```
name: Powershell script
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  myJob:
    name: PS - Update list
    runs-on: self-hosted

    steps:
      - name: Check out repository code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 1
      
      - name: Run PowerShell script
        shell: pwsh7
        env:
          Creds: ${{ secrets.Creds }}
        run: | 
          ./Something.ps1
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: With `shell: pwsh7`, is it not working? Is `pwsh7` the correct command and available in the `PATH`?

Comment: See [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].shell`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell) for Windows shell invocation i.e. `pwsh -command ". '{0}'"` or `powershell -command ". '{0}'"`. You can configure Powershell accordingly.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to replace `shell: pwsh7` with `shell: pwsh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everyones comments!
As Mathias wrote in a comment i had to use 'shell: pwsh' instead this always uses powershell 7 as default. If you're gonna use an earlier version like powershell 5 then you need to change this to something else i belive.